# getting a string from text view into a double in android

Tags: android, string, floating-point, firebase-realtime-database, double

Can someone help me with this problem am experiencing. I am trying to get a number from a text view and storing it into a double for calculation. Can someone help me where i went wrong?

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                total += Float.parseFloat((String) snapshot.child("totalCost").getValue());
                totalNew.setText(String.valueOf(total).toString().trim());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    mnewRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Long role = (Long) dataSnapshot.child("barberPercentage").getValue();

            percentage.setText(String.valueOf(role));



            num1 = Double.parseDouble(totalNew.getText().toString().trim());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(percentage.getText().toString());
            sum = num1  *(num2/100);

            wage.setText(Double.toString(sum));
```

I am getting an error of this, I have trying many ways to change float to double and vice versa but yet to work.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Number"
                                                            at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
                                                            at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
                                                            at com.starcutz.employer.AdminIndividualBarberWageActivity$2.onDataChange(AdminIndividualBarberWageActivity.java:90)
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

what should i do? as when i remove these values the totalNew Textview and percentage Textview are populated.

```
 num1 = Double.parseDouble(totalNew.getText().toString().trim()); num2 = Double.parseDouble(percentage.getText().toString()); sum = num1 *(num2/100); wage.setText(Double.toString(sum));
```

Comment: Which line is it crashing on?

Comment: this line here num1 = Double.parseDouble(totalNew.getText().toString().trim());

Comment: Judging by the error, it looks like you are trying to convert the string "Number". So it seems like your input it incorrect.

Comment: what should i do? as when i remove these  values  the totalNew Textview and percentage Textview are populated.                (num1 = Double.parseDouble(totalNew.getText().toString().trim());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(percentage.getText().toString());
            sum = num1  *(num2/100);

            wage.setText(Double.toString(sum));

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the rest of your code, however, you need to figure out why the string you are passing is the word "Number"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
num1 = Double.parseDouble(totalNew.getText().toString());
```

Or

```
num1 = Double.valueOf(totalNew.getText().toString());
```

Comment: still the same problem